# ionic view title alignment

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to make new app using ionic framework.I have used the `sidemenu` project to make my app.But i am facing the title alignment problem.In `android 4.4`,The title is not showing correctly.But in `android 5` is worked perfectly.

[**android 5**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtATS.png)

[**android 4.4**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5wDM.jpg)

Comment: Can you show some line of code?

Comment: this is code  . <ion-view view-title="درباره برنامه">
  <ion-content>
    <p class="paraav2" style="margin-top:10px;">سازنده : <span>علیرضا بابایی</span></p>
    <p class="paraav2">ورژن برنامه : <span>1.0</span></p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>